# How can i check if data is " "

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

How can i check if data is blank but not null
the data is == " " but it still proceeds to the else statement.

Here is my code :

```
@if(App\Company::all()->first()->logo == " ")
    <br>
@else
    <img src='.{{ App\Company::all()->first()->getLogoAttribute()}}' style=" width: 20%;">
@endif
```

Comment: `""` is not `" "`

Comment: try with `@if(! App\Company::all()->first()->logo)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is_null()` and the `empty()` method:

```
<?php $logo = App\Company::all()->first()->logo;
@if(is_null($logo) == false && empty($logo) == true)
    <br>
@else
    <img src='.{{ App\Company::all()->first()->getLogoAttribute()}}' style=" width: 20%;">
@endif
```